# List navigation menu moves around when minimizing browser [CSS, HTML]

Tags: html, css, browser, menu

I made a fixed menu bar for my homepage in css using a list. It looks fine, but when I minimize the browser, the menu items move to the left, which I don't want them to do.

How can I prevent that and make the browser keep the position of the menu the way it is, if necessary the browser could add a horizontal scroll bar, but the menu shouldn't move around.

Can anyone help, please?

Here is the HTML coode:

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <li style="list-style: none;"> <img src="images/head.png"/><br></li>
    <div id='cssmenu'>      
        <ul>           
            <li><a href='index.html'><span>xxx</span></a></li>  
            <li><a href='index.html'><span>xxx</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='index.html'><span>xxx</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='index.html'><span>xxx</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='index.html'><span>xxx</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='index.html'><span>xxx</span></a></li>  
       </ul>
   </div>       
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code - Menu Navigation Bar:

```
   #cssmenu
   {
       position: relative;
       margin: 0 auto;
       clear: both; 
   }

   #cssmenu a 
   {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;    
   }

   #cssmenu li 
   {   
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      padding-top: 7px;
      display: block; 
      width: 160px; 
      float: right; 
      margin: 0 10px;
   }

   #cssmenu ul
   {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 20px;
      margin-bottom: -70px;
          max-height: 80px;
    }

   #cssmenu li a 
   {  
      padding-top: 8px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 10px; 

      border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
      text-decoration: none;    
      display: block;

      border-radius: 2px;
      -moz-border-radius: 2px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
          -khtml-border-radius: 2px;    

       font-size: 17px;
       font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;
      color: #292F33;
     }

     #cssmenu li:hover a 
     {  
         border-bottom: 3px solid #30B0FF;  
         display: block;
         color: #30B0FF;
         clear: both;

        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;

        transition-duration: 0.1s;
        transition-delay: 0.03s;
      }

     #menu
     {      
         height: 86px;  
         width: 100%;
         float: center;

         padding-top: 10px;
         padding-right: 20px;
         padding-left: 20px;        
         margin-left: -20px;
         margin-top: -106px;    

         font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;  
         font-size: 15px;
             position: fixed;  

         border: 5px solid #292F33;
             box-shadow: 0px 0px 125px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
         background-color: #fff;
         color: #292F33;
      }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ pls

Comment: that's what it looks like: http://ivan.ilic.hg-gf.de/Lazarus.html (It work for the Lazarus page only, the other links aren't set yet) :)

Comment: OK, what's about letting the menu items move to the left (depending on screen width, when minimizing browser) until there's a collision between the image and the menu items/list items?? Then they should stop moving. (I know, it's easier to use bootstrap, but I would like to code it myself, and I don't really know bootstrap)

Comment: I'll give bootstrap a chance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the width of the #menu div. Now it is `width:100%`, so when de body is minimized, the #menu div too. If you set a size of, for example, 1200px, this size will not change when the body is minimized.

I tested it with Chrome CSS editor on your page and it works.

So,

```
#menu {
height: 86px;
width: 1200px;
float: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-left: -20px;
margin-top: -106px;
font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;
font-size: 15px;
position: fixed;
border: 5px solid #292F33;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 125px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
background-color: #fff;
color: #292F33;
}
```

**EDITED:**

Also set:

```
body{
min-width:1200px;
}
```

Comment: yeah, it works, thanks. But when I minimize the browser, there is no horizontal scroll bar and I can't see the whole page...

Answer (score 1):

The below code works. I have tested this myself in Chormium CSS editor. All you need to do is add `min-width: 1200px` or something suitable to your need, then change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`

```
#menu {
    height: 86px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    float: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -106px;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid #292F33;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 125px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #292F33;
}
```

Comment: but now, the menu bar isn't fixed, anymore. My goal was to code a fixed menu like the one on the soundcloud page, or twitter...

Comment: Next time try bootstrap. It will save you a lot of work.

Comment: but if the menu is fixed you cant select other links on them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this style Done :-

```
#cssmenu li{
    width: 12%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning it to "absolute" rather than "relative".

For making it more good try applying bootstrap.